# How can I remove the border bottom lines of grid rows?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

How can I remove the border bottom  lines of grid rows?

I needed the text to be displayed without any limit, as if it were a white page.

Fiddle:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1boq

Comment: I want to try something with property cls: 'customrows' but I can not identify the sass / css that renders the bottom line you see in each row on the fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your fiddle example, it is better to do the style thing through overwriting the CSS.

Add one config into grid panel with `cls: 'remove-border'`. You can use any name here.

Then inside CSS (where I created a test.css inside root) use the following to overwrite:

```
.remove-border .x-grid-with-row-lines .x-grid-item {
    border-color: transparent;
}
```

With this way, you can do any style change inside the CSS. Here is the modified example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1bou

Comment: No problem. If you have any other things, let me know,

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the bottom border using `viewConfig`:

```
viewConfig: {
    border : '0 0 1 0',
    style : {
        borderColor : 'transparent'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gaurav.I could not run your solution on my fiddle with success. Can you test on my fiddle please (your solution is very interesting)? I edited my fiddle with  your code.